# Generating the set of all strings within a fixed edit distance of a initial string?

Tags: string-manipulation, algorithm

Provided a starting string `initialString`, and a particular alphabet of allowed characters `{"A","B","C","D","E",...}`, how can I generate the set of all strings such that `EditDistance[initialString,setElement] = k`, where `k` is specified as desired?  How can I do the same if I only consider `HammingDistance`?

Rather, I should say, how do we do the above without generating all of the `Tuples` of relevant length, then checking each one for `EditDistance` or `HammingDistance`, which is probably the most naive way to proceed?

Here's a partial example of that naive strategy (partial because for `EditDistance` we need to generate tuples of the string length of the initial string $\pm \space k$):

```
k = 1;

stringTestLength = 8;

alphabet = {"0", "1", "R"};

tuples = Map[StringJoin, Tuples[alphabet, stringTestLength]];

testString = "00000000"

distanceOneList = {};
editDistanceCounter = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[tuples], i++,
  If[EditDistance[tuples[[i]], testString] == k,
    editDistanceCounter += 1;
    distanceOneList = Append[distanceOneList, tuples[[i]]];
    ];
  ];

distanceOneList
editDistanceCounter
```

The output here is of course the following length sixteen array:

```
{"00000001", "0000000Q", "00000010", "000000Q0", "00000100", "00000Q00", "00001000", "0000Q000", "00010000", "000Q0000", "00100000", "00Q00000", "01000000", "0Q000000", "10000000", "Q0000000"};
```

The "real" answer for `EditDistance` is 1 (for the length 7 tuple set) + 19 (for the length 9 tuple set) + 16 (for the length 8 = length of the initial string) tuple set.  Thus, there are 36 strings over this alphabet within `EditDistance k = 1` of the initial string `"00000000"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kAwayWordsF[str_, dist_, alph_, strlen_] := Module[{len = StringLength[str], dict}, 
    dict = StringJoin /@ Tuples[alph, strlen]; 
     With[{nf = Nearest[dict]},  
       Complement[nf[str, {Infinity, dist}], nf[str, {Infinity, dist - 1}]]]]   
kAwayWordsF["00000000",1,{"0","1","Q"},8]
(* {"00000001", "0000000Q", "00000010", "000000Q0", "00000100", "00000Q00", "00001000",
    "0000Q000", "00010000", "000Q0000", "00100000", "00Q00000", "01000000", "0Q000000",
    "10000000","Q0000000"} *)
kAwayWordsF["00000000",2,{"0","1","Q"},7]
(* {"0000001", "000000Q", "0000010", "00000Q0", "0000100", "0000Q00","0001000",
   "000Q000", "0010000", "00Q0000", "0100000", "0Q00000","1000000", "Q000000"}  *)
```

**Update:** Removing the restriction that target strings have the same string length as the teststring:

```
distKWordsF[str_, dist_, alph_] := Module[{len = StringLength[str], dict},
   dict = StringJoin /@ Join @@ (Tuples[alph, #] & /@ Range[len - dist, len + dist]);
   With[{nf = Nearest[dict]}, 
      Complement[nf[str, {Infinity, dist}], nf[str, {Infinity, dist - 1}]]]]
distKWordsF["00000000", 1, {"0", "1", "Q"}]
 (*{"0000000","000000000","000000001","00000000Q","00000001","000000010",
    "0000000Q","0000000Q0", "00000010","000000100","000000Q0","000000Q00",
    "00000100", "000001000","00000Q00","00000Q000","00001000","000010000",
   "0000Q000","0000Q0000","00010000","000100000","000Q0000","000Q00000",
   "00100000","001000000", "00Q00000","00Q000000","01000000","010000000","0Q000000",
   "0Q0000000","10000000","100000000","Q0000000","Q00000000"}*)
(Length@distKWordsF["00000000", #, {"0", "1", "Q"}]) & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
(*{{36,472,3740,22096,110036}*)
```

Comment: Great!  So this is for the HammingDistance case.  Is there a way to get Nearest to work for EditDistance?

Comment: @Cray, this is for the `EditDistance` b/c the default `DistanceFunction` for `Nearest` with string data is `EditDistance`.

Comment: Ah, I see, see we just need to join / concatenate the answers for $\pm k$ length strings, no?

Comment: Not sure how to deal with `HammingDistance`. First, `DistanceFunction` option is available only for the two-argument input pattern for `Nearest`; the syntax `Nearest[data, DistanceFunction->sth]` does not work, so we need to use the form to map `Nearest[data,#,DistanceFunction->sth]&` to the list of target strings (and this is much slower than the approach `nf=Nearest[data]; nf/@targetlist`. Second, `HammingDistance` only works for strings with equal stringlengths ...

Comment: ... Regarding "joining answers for `+-k` length strings", I don't think it would work (`EditDistance` is always less than or equal to `HammingDistance`)

Comment: I don't understand, shouldn't the set of strings within edit distance 'k' be larger than the set of strings within Hamming distance 'k'?  Don't we need to consider the relevant larger or shorter strings for Edit Distance?  This is commensurate with the edit distance between two arbitrary strings being less than or equal to the Hamming distance.

Comment: @Cray, right on both points. Updating the post with a version that considers words with different string lengths.